# How to configure saving strategy (append) for belongsToMany Association?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have a belongsToMany association which deletes joinTable data because i just put new connections inside the entity to be persited.
So i read [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations) about the 2 strategys: append and replace.
Replace is the default one. But i could not find out yet how to set it to append strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define belongsToMany relation with `saveStrategy` keyword which accept either append or replace. So code should be like

```
$this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
            'joinTable' => 'articles_tags',
            'saveStrategy' => 'append'
        ]);
```

For more check official [Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)