# Multiple identical entitiy relation

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've got a `products`, `attributes`, and `product_attributes` table.
Each product can have multiple `attributes` and these relations were stored in `product_attributes`, so far so good.
But a product can have the same attribute multiple times. I just only can link different attributes to a product.

For example:

> **Audi**(product) has **Wheel**(attribute): **Amount**(joinData) = 2;
>   **Value**(joinData) = "front";

And

> **Audi**(product) has **Wheel**(attribute): **Amount**(joinData) = 2;
>   **Value**(joinData) = "rear";

Only the attribute wheel with **value** rear is saved the front wheels are lost.

No errors in controller.

This is the output of `$this->request->getData()`

```
/src/Controller/ProductsController.php (line 62)
[
    'type_id' => '12',
    'name' => 'Audi',
    'thumbnail' => '',
    'image' => '',
    'attributes' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'unique_id' => '9',
            '_joinData' => [
                'amount' => '2',
                'value' => '1',
                'information' => 'front'
            ]
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'unique_id' => '9',
            '_joinData' => [
                'amount' => '2',
                'value' => '1',
                'information' => 'rear'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

This is the output of `$product` after patchEntity:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

    'type_id' => (int) 12,
    'name' => 'Audi',
    'thumbnail' => '',
    'image' => '',
    'attributes' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Attribute) {

            'unique_id' => (int) 9,
            'category_id' => (int) 8,
            'name' => 'VDSL2',
            'unit' => '',
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\ProductsAttribute) {

                'amount' => (int) 2,
                'value' => (float) 1,
                'information' => 'rear',
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'amount' => true,
                    'value' => true,
                    'information' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'ProductsAttributes'

            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                '_joinData' => [
                    'amount' => '2',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'information' => 'front'
                ]
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Attributes'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Attribute) {

            'unique_id' => (int) 9,
            'category_id' => (int) 8,
            'name' => 'VDSL2',
            'unit' => '',
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\ProductsAttribute) {

                'amount' => (int) 2,
                'value' => (float) 1,
                'information' => 'rear',
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'amount' => true,
                    'value' => true,
                    'information' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'ProductsAttributes'

            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                '_joinData' => [
                    'amount' => '2',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'information' => 'front'
                ]
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Attributes'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'type_id' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'thumbnail' => true,
        'image' => true,
        'type' => true,
        'attributes' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'type_id' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'thumbnail' => true,
        'image' => true,
        'attributes' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Products'

}
```

ProductController Add function:

```
public function add(){
        $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData(), [
                'associated' => [
                     'Attributes',
                     'Attributes._joinData'
                ]
            ]);
            /*debug($this->request->getData());
            debug($product);
            die();*/
            if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $types = $this->Products->Types->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $attributes = $this->Products->Attributes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('product', 'types', 'attributes'));
}
```

It has something to do with my relations.

Product Table:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Attributes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'attribute_id',
    'joinTable' => 'products_attributes'
]);
```

Attribute Table:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Products', [
    'foreignKey' => 'attribute_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'product_id',
    'joinTable' => 'products_attributes'
]);
```

These are the attributes `product_attributes` have in the DB:

```
unique_iq INT,
product_id INT,
attribute_id INT,
amount INT,
value DOUBLE,
information VARCHAR(150)
```

Save Strategy doesn't solve my problem. Still same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure saving strategy (append) for belongsToMany Association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428439/how-to-configure-saving-strategy-append-for-belongstomany-association)

Comment: @arilia saveStrategy didn't solve my problem the results are still the same.

Comment: so you have to show us the data you pass to the entity _before_ it is patched

Comment: @arilia I've updated my question. Now you can see what patchEntity does with the data I submit to the controller.

Comment: what is that unique_id?

Comment: `unique_id` is the primary_key of the `attributes` table, the primary_key of `products` is also called `unique_id` aswell as `product_attributes`'s primary_key.
@arilia

Comment: I replicated your code and I had the same behavior. Either it is a bug or - more likely - there is another way to do this but I must admit I would have done like you did. Sorry I can't help you

Comment: The problem is that [**the merging process is based on the primary key**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.6.4/src/ORM/Marshaller.php#L417-L446), ie there will only be a single entity queried and placed in a `PK => Entity` map, causing all merge operations for that primary key to happen on one and the same entity, leaving you with the last merge operation, ie the two `Attribute` entities you are seeing there are one and the same instance. AFAIR this is not considered a bug, but a limitation - might still be worth to report it, maybe something can be done about in 4.x. @arilia

Comment: It is like setting product's PK and attribute's PK  as primary key. That's a huge limitation if it is one. I will report that issue asap. I decided to use Cake bc. time was a huge factor of the development now I feel frustrated :(

Comment: You're not a real programmer if you've never started your day full of joy and confidence, just to find yourself lying on the ground crying, praying to god for a quick death after spending 15 hours with debugging problems - that's the programmer's life :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a workaround but it should work. Waiting for a more cake way

Since you basically want to fill `products` and `product_attributes` tables you can set a new relationship this way

**Product Table:**

```
$this->hasMany('ProductsAttributes', [ /* configure keys here */ ]);
```

And shape you data this way

```
[
    'type_id' => '12',
    'name' => 'Audi',
    'thumbnail' => '',
    'image' => '',
    'products_attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute_id' => '9',
            'amount' => '2',
            'value' => '1',
            'information' => 'front'
        ],
        [
            'attribute_id' => '9',
            'amount' => '2',
            'value' => '1',
            'information' => 'rear'
        ]
    ]
]
```

This will create a new row in `products` and two new rows in `product_attributes`

Comment: I am now out of office and I will let monday in the morning (UTC) know if it worked out. But it seems very promising. Thank you for the work you did. Appreciate your passion you put in this case ^^

Comment: Thank you for your work you put on this case. This work-around worked incredibly well.